# passing three parameters from jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services

I have a autocomplete textbox, and I need to fetch the students who are all in a particular degree and semester, for this am collecting the degreeId and store it in globally declared variable and am collecting the semester, now I need to pass the autocomplete textbox value,degreeId and semester....for this I tried to call my webservice like,

```
$("#txtStudents").autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/DataService.asmx/SearchStudents",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

           data: "{ 'searchTerm': '"+ JSON.stringify($("#txtStudents").val())+ "','degreeId': '"+JSON.stringify(degreeId)+"','semester': '"+JSON.stringify($("#ddlSemester :selected").text())+"'}",

            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
```

and I receive this call in webservice as,

```
public string SearchStudents(string searchTerm, string degreeId, string semester)
{}
```

I have a class to fetch the student details for the particular semester and in the particular degree,as

```
public class SearchStudents : List<SearchStudent>
{
    DataAccess.Entities buDateEntities = new DataAccess.Entities();

    public SearchStudents(string searchTerm)
    {
        //int sem = Convert.ToInt32(semester);
        //int degree = Convert.ToInt32(degreeId);

        foreach (DataAccess.Student student in buDateEntities.Students.Where(s => s.IsDeleted == false
                                                                            // && s.DegreeId==degree
                                                                             //&& s.CurrentSemester==semester
                                                                             && ((s.FirstName.IndexOf(searchTerm) == 0 || s.MiddleName.IndexOf(searchTerm) == 0 || s.LastName.IndexOf(searchTerm) == 0)
                                                                               )|| s.USN.IndexOf(searchTerm) == 0).OrderBy(s => s.FirstName).Take(5))
        {
            this.Add(new SearchStudent(student.StudentId
                                    , student.FirstName
                                    , student.MiddleName
                                    , student.LastName
                                    , student.Photo
                                    , student.USN
                                    , student.Email
                                    , student.Mobile));
        }            
    }
}
```

how do I call(I need to pass searchTerm,degreeId,semester) this class from the webservice....

Comment: ‘data‘ must be a javascript object literal, there you have a  string

Comment: then how can I pass, is there anyother way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
...

data: {
    searchTerm : $("#txtStudents").val(),
    degreeId   : degreeId,
    semester   : $("#ddlSemester :selected").text()
},

...
```

Define it this way, it should work

Comment: are you working on a GET or a POST request? How is coded you web service? Are you sure it works the plain old way without ajax? Try to  die($_GET/$_POST) as soon as the webservice receives data ... or just post its code

Comment: its working when I simply passing the searchTerm alone, like      data: "{'searchTerm' : '" + $("#txtStudents").val() + "'}", but when I try to pass all the three parameters its showing the error

Comment: Your js is valid, so the error is most likely on the server side

Comment: If the error is in the server code, and you don't post it, how can I, or anyone else, be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

```
data: {
    searchTerm : $("#txtStudents").val(),
    degreeId   : degreeId,
    semester   : $("#ddlSemester :selected").text()
},
```

Convert your server function paramenters to string, as what i can see is you are passing string overthere and in parameter you have int.

```
public string SearchStudents(string searchTerm, string degreeId, string semester)
```

**Note**: Better if you `Json.Stringify` all parameteres.

Comment: am new to jquery, how to use stringify for autocomplete, can you give me some idea or code example here

Comment: searchTerm : Json.Stringify($("#txtStudents").val()),

Comment: great, I just put the query as data: "{ 'searchTerm': '"+ JSON.stringify($("#txtStudents").val())+ "','degreeId': '"+JSON.stringify(degreeId)+"','semester': '"+JSON.stringify($("#ddlSemester :selected").text())+"'}",.......and the webservice is getting fired, but the ddl selected item is not displayed

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exact problem you are facing

Comment: i just used the query as  data: "{ 'searchTerm': '" + $("#txtStudents").val() + "','degreeId': '" + JSON.stringify(degreeId) + "','semester': '" + $("select[id$=ddlSemester]").val() + "'}",

Comment: you can directly call your method and pass the values to that method as a parameter.. do you want to respond back that method to ajax function, is that you are asking>?